# Render a Web JS Variable within an ExpressJS statement

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am attempting to render the variable `cat` which is a string within an ExpressJS statement AND a script tag.

Here is my code:

```html
<script>
            function detectChange() {
                var place;
                cat = document.getElementById("catType").value; // coollink
                type = document.getElementById("appType").value;
                
                if(type == "application") {
                    place = `<%= certain.categories.find(o => o.link == cat).placeholder %>`;
                } else {
                    place = 'Topic description...';
                };
                document.getElementsByName('description')[1].innerHTML = place;
            };
</script>
```

The specific part I have a problem with is:

```js
 place = `<%= certain.categories.find(o => o.link == cat).placeholder %>`;
```

I want to display `cat`, which is a WebJS Variable (that for now has a value of `coollink`) inside of my ExpressJS tags `<%= coollink %>` however I cannot seem to display it without it erroring and telling me it has an error with compiling it.

It works just fine if I change it to say

```js
place = `<%= certain.categories.find(o => o.link == 'coollink').placeholder %>`;
```

but then it's not dynamic, and it needs to be dynamic for this project.

Comment: You can set a Web JS variable = to an ExpressJS variable. But not the other way around, if there is a solution I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to accessing client side javascript variable from server side nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839872/how-to-accessing-client-side-javascript-variable-from-server-side-nodejs)

Comment: Or [Get variable on client-side from the server-side (express.js, node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23031161/215552)

Comment: I really would recommend you to make it easier by AJAX request so that you seperate logics and you minimize server side computations by a client request and server response to get this value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can't do this.**

The code inside `<%= %>` runs on the server side, the `cat` variable doesn't even exist yet.

What `<%= %>` do is place any string in this place. It doesn't even know it's a script.

The best you can do is:

```
<%= certain.categories %>.find(o => o.link == cat).placeholder
```

But it will expose all categories to the user

Comment: only through inspect element though right?

Comment: Yes, only though inspect element.